# Syntax error with Elif Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn Python, and I'm making a text rpg as practice. The function below was designed to randomly assign npc stats, based on percentages, that vary from class to class.

```
def mob_Stat_Assign(self, level): 
    statCount = (3 * self.level)
    while(statCount > 0):
        statRoll = random.randrange(1, 101)            
        if(statRoll >= (100 - self.statS)):
            self.strength += 1
        elif((statRoll >= (100 - (self.statP + self.statS)) and (statRoll < (100 - self.statS))):
            self.perception += 1
        elif((statRoll >= (100 - (self.statE + self.statP + self.statS) and (statRoll <(100 - (self.statP + self.statS)))):
            self.endurance += 1
        elif((statRoll >= (100 - (self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)) and (statRoll < (100 - (self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)))):
            self.charisma += 1
        elif((statRoll >= (100 - (self.statI + self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)) and (statRoll < (100 - (self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)))):
            self.intelligence += 1
        elif((statRoll >= (100 - (self.statA + self.statI + self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)) and (statRoll < (100 - (self.statI + self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS))
            self.agility += 1 
        else:
            self.luck += 1
        statCount -= 1
```

When I try to compile, I get an error stating invalid syntax, and the colon at the end of the first elif statement is highlighted.

I was able to fix this by putting (100 -(self.statP + self.statS)) into a variable, and subbing that in, but then there was the same error on the next elif statement.
I'm sure I can fix the whole function by defining  variables for the conditional in a similar manner for all the statements, but I would really like to know why this doesn't work as is.

I don't see the difference between

```
(statRoll >= (100 - (self.statP + self.statS))
```

and

```
x = (100 - (self.statP + self.statS))
(statRoll >= x)
```

Comment: Count out your parentheses, carefully.

Comment: Using better names would help a lot. What's `statP`? Why use `statRoll` instead of `roll`? It is unconventional (that is, hard to read) camelCase_Especially_With_Underscores. A [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses don't match up, you are missing a closing `)` parens in the expression:

```
elif(
    (
        statRoll >= (
            100 - (self.statP + self.statS)
        ) and (
            statRoll < (100 - self.statS)
        # ?
    )
):
```

You don't need half those parentheses; if you put a space between `elif` and the expression you don't need the outer pair. Next you can cut more of those parentheses in the sums (`a - b + c` won't be confused easily). If fact, you don't need *any* but putting some around the arithmetic may aid in readability a little:

```
elif statRoll >= (100 - self.statP + self.statS) and statRoll < (100 - self.statS):
```

Applying this to all your tests, plus a little PEP-8 re-arranging, gives:

```
if statRoll >= (100 - self.statS):
    self.strength += 1
elif (statRoll >= (100 - self.statP + self.statS) and
        statRoll < (100 - self.statS)):
    self.perception += 1
elif (statRoll >= (100 - self.statE + self.statP + self.statS) and 
        statRoll < (100 - self.statP + self.statS)):
    self.endurance += 1
elif (statRoll >= (100 - self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS) and
        statRoll < (100 - self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)):
    self.charisma += 1
elif (statRoll >= (100 - self.statI + self.statC + self.statE + 
                   self.statP + self.statS) and
        statRoll < (100 - self.statC + self.statE + self.statP + self.statS)):
    self.intelligence += 1
elif (statRoll >= (100 - self.statA + self.statI + self.statC + 
                   self.statE + self.statP + self.statS) and
        statRoll < (100 - self.statI + self.statC + self.statE +
                    self.statP + self.statS)):
    self.agility += 1 
else:
    self.luck += 1
```

Still not the most readable however; consider adding functions to break down those calculations.

Comment: Ah wow that fixed it right up. I had heard "when in doubt, use parentheses." I guess I took that too seriously. Thanks for the help!